# how do I prevent my postgres connection from timing out? (python, psycopg2)

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, python

very quick one from me: I have a python script that runs continuously, keeping an eye on a postgres database. I've set up a listening channel and everytime a relevant change is made, the script gets a notification and does something accordingly.

the problem I'm having is that sometimes there are hours between notifications and my connection simply "drops" after a while. that means even though a change is taking place, the connection is not active anymore, hence python won't get a notification and everything technically stops.

is there a parameters that can be used to prevent that from happening? when I was using php/mysql, there was a persistent connection option. does postgres have something similar? this is what I currently use to connect:

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432')
    conn.set_session(autocommit = True)
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    print('Database connection OK\n')
except:
    print('Database connection error\n')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Postgres has `idle_session_timeout` which does close connections when enabled so check that via `show idle_session_timeout;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't drop idle connections. It must be something else, probably a misconfigured firewall.

To defend against that, set the parameter [`tcp_keepalives_idle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-KEEPALIVES-IDLE) on the server to something less than the default 2 hours.

There is also a corresponding parameter [`keepalives_idle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-KEEPALIVES-IDLE) on the client side that you could set when you connect with psycopg2.

Both should do the trick.